# IPhone apps in Flash CS6

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

I want to develop an application for IOS. What are the restrictions while developing from Flash cs6. Does Appstore approves application created from Flash Cs6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html

Create an AIR for Mobile project with Flash Professional or Flash Builder and to publish you need an apple developer certificate.

I suggest you google about it, there are lot of video tutorials and resources.

Comment: Does Appstore approves our applications(FLASH app)?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh , yes Apple will approve it and your app will be on AppStore if it passes the general apps guidelines (but that includes native apps as well so do not worry about using AS3 or Flex)